# How to access JSON array values without using index

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I have made a request to an API that is returning a JSON array like this:

[image]

My end goal is to take the attribute "State" and find all the "EventName" (s) where `State: "PR"` (or another state. I am getting the State input from a user dropdown) and put that into a list.

I know I can use the index (Ex: `event_data[0].State` returns "PR") to get the individual attributes but how can I avoid using the index to get all the `State` value (or `EventName` values) in the entire Array? Or is that even wise?
I have tried the below, but it seemed to just grab all of the `EventName` values rather than just those for "PR". The expected output should be a list of event names for just "PR" like `pr_list = ["Debby 2000", "Dean 2001", "Jeane 2004" ... "Maria 2017"];`

```
pr_list = [];
for (i = 0; i < event_data.length; i++) {
  state_data = event_data[i].State;
  if (state_data = "PR") {
    console.log(event_data[i].EventName)
    pr_list.append(event_data[i].EventName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share expected output

Comment: you're missing == in the `if` statement: `if (state_data = "PR")` - you're performing assignment, not comparison, thats why it takes all `eventName` and not just those with State equal to "PR"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this:

```js
filtered_events = event_data.filter(event => (event.State === "PR"));
pr_list = filtered_events.map(event => event.EventName);
```

---

Regarding your existing code - you have a typo:

```js
if (state_data = "PR") { ... }
```

should be:

```js
if (state_data === "PR") { ... }
```

([more info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness))

Comment: This works great up front but I just want the EventName values in a list for "PR". `pr_list = event_data.filter(event.EventName => (event.State === "PR"))` doesn't quite work though.

Comment: @gwydion93 I noticed that after I posted my answer - it should do what you want now

Comment: That works perfect! It was the `filter` that was the key.

Answer (score 2):

**Native Way**

```js
const finalArray = [];
const event_data = [{ EventName: 'Event1', State: 'PR' }, { EventName: 'Event2', State: 'PQ' }];
for (i = 0; i < event_data.length; i += 1) {
  element = event_data[i];
  if (element.State === "PR") {
    finalArray.push(element.EventName);
  }
}
console.log(finalArray);
```

**ES6 Way**

```js
const event_data = [{ EventName: 'Event1', State: 'PR' }, { EventName: 'Event2', State: 'PQ' }];
const finalArray = event_data.filter((f) => {
  return f.State &&
    f.State === 'PR';
}).map((m) => { return m.EventName; });
console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this:

```
pr_list = event_data.filter(event => (event.State === "PR")).map(event => event.EventName)
```

for unicity use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) :

```
pr_list = [...new Set(event_data.filter(event => (event.State === "PR")).map(event => event.EventName))]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can using `array.filter()` function to get list have state is `PR` and `array.map()` function to get all `eventId` of list.

```js
var array = [
  {eventId: '1', State: 'PR'},
  {eventId: '2', State: 'AR'},
  {eventId: '3', State: 'PR'}
];

// get all event with State is PR
array = array.filter(function (event) {
  return event.State === "PR";
});

// put all eventId in new array
var eventIds = array.map(function (event) {
   return event.eventId
});

console.log('eventIds:', eventIds);
```

Comment: I like this solution. I would use eventName instead but it may be useful to have a new array rather than just a list.

Comment: Ok, this is demo code so it is maybe not perfect. I'm happy to know that you like this solution.